# The leading underscore not recommended nowadays for labels?

Tags: assembly, nasm

As a newbie, I wonder, is the leading underscore not recommended to use nowadays in assembly anymore? For example:

```
section .text
  global start ;; good
  ;; global _start ;; bad

  start:
```

That is, all the labels shouldn't not have the leading undercore in their names? It used to be used in 10-30 years ago, but nowadays not, right?

Comment: It is still used by C compilers for certain calling conventions. I presume that is why you're remembering it as being common 10-30 years ago, for interoperability purposes, and that still hasn't changed.

Comment: @CodyGray, my question is a yes-no question.

Comment: There is no way to give a yes/no answer to this. You're asking about some kind of nebulous "recommendation" or "best practice", and that just doesn't exist.

Comment: @CodyGray, I think it does.

Comment: On what basis do you think that? What group of people would have gotten together and decided what is and is not recommended?

Comment: @CodyGray, the same kind of group of people that do that in other programming languages.

Comment: Which is *no one*.

Comment: @CodyGray, you're saying there's no naming convention in any other language.

Comment: @Jodooomi What CodyGray is saying is that the underscore mangling depends on the compiler, OS, language, calling convention and architecture. If you want a  yes/no question, please pick 1) one and only one language 2) one and only one compiler 3)one and only one OS 4) one and only one calling convention 5) one and only one architecture.

Comment: I think leading underscore hurts readability of source, so the yes/no answer is "not recommended", and I can't recall times when it was recommended. But your example is using `start`, which sort of implies it may be the special entry-point label used by the toolchain during linking executable. Then the underscore may be required by particular combination of linker+target and linker script. But for "your" labels in the source the answer is simple "no".

Comment: @Ped7g, how about Alexey Frunze's answer about compatibility/interoperability issues?

Comment: Nobody sane will design any tool-chain in such way, that it will interfere with non-underscore labels, because those are natural to use locally inside the source. If you are asking about external global symbols used to link against other libraries, then I'm not sure what you mean by compatibility/interoperability issues, as every target environment will have it's own ABI, so calling for example `printf` on different platforms will need more changes (like different way of passing arguments), adding/removing underscore will be irrelevant minor detail then. Assembly is generally not portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's possible to run into compatibility/interoperability issues with other code (when both are linked together statically or dynamically) or with tools (e.g. when the leading underscores have some special meaning/purpose in the linker or debugger), then you should follow what's common for your tools and platform.

Otherwise it's entirely up to you. For example, I've written a C compiler that generates assembly code, which is then assembled into ELF object files, which are then linked together with the standard library. This process is the same when compiling for DOS, Windows or Linux. In all cases public/global symbols have leading underscores even though it's common not to have those in ELF files. They in no way pose problems for the OS as the OS doesn't see those names (the executables simply don't contain symbol tables, which are not required for execution anyway). I have my own linker and my own standard library. I don't have interoperability issues with anything like glibc (I'm using system calls in my standard library). IOW, in the small world around my compiler the underscores aren't an issue at all. They may become an issue if the compiler gains popularity (doubtful) and people start using it in new, interesting and unintended ways. But until then things just work.

Comment: so not to use underscores?

Comment: @Jodooomi No underscores if you're writing for Linux or BSD. Except for the entry point label, which is expected to be `_start`.

Comment: @Jodooomi There's too much variation for Windows because there are many different compilers for Windows, including Visual Studio and various flavors of gcc (MinGW, Cygwin) among the top. And even in Visual Studio there are multiple variants. See, e.g. [Decorated Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx).