# Naming convention for labels, functions

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm confused a bit and still haven't found an explicit answer: should  I name  labels as just "label1" or with underscore "_label1"? What's the most popular and recognizable way? I've even seen one with dot ".label1" if I remember correctly.

The same  question **goes for functions**: "function1" or "_function1"?

Comment: What operating system? What architecture? What calling convention? All these questions influence the answer.

Comment: @fuz, windows, linux, x32, x86-64, stdcall, fastcall, cdecl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The leading underscore not recommended nowadays for labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529300/the-leading-underscore-not-recommended-nowadays-for-labels)

Comment: @ako25 You sure you mean x32 and not x86-32?

Comment: @fuz,,,,.. yes.

Comment: @ako25: Well then. On Linux, don't decorate anything. On Windows, the decoration depends on the calling convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a code maintainability viewpoint, leading dots and underscores don't add any useful information to a label, so if there is no specific need for those prefixes (see below), you should get rid of them. Just the fact that you may think "it looks fancy" is not enough reason to use them.

Dots are sometimes used by assemblers to specify that a label is *local*, i.e. not to be exported as a symbol to the object file. This can be useful in order to not pollute the global name space with symbols you do not need.

Other assemblers use dots to denote an *assembler directive* and do not allow dots in symbols at all.

Underscores are typically used by assembler code that has to integrate with higher-level languages. Some C compilers prefix all exported symbols with underscores, and in order to be able to be callable from C code, assembler functions need to follow this rule.

Generally, your assembler (and/or compiler, in case you integrate with compiled code) manual should be able to tell you what variations your specific assembler supports or requires. And if the manual doesn't explicitly tell you when and why you should use such prefixes, simply don't use them - Assembler labels are one (the minimal and most important) part of self-documenting your code. Don't waste that for meaningless prefixes if you don't need to.

Comment: by the way, what about the indentation for code below section .data or section .bss or any other section -- is it recommended to insert indentation for the code or declarations below or not? I can't figure out what's more popular, I keep seeing both approaches.

Comment: @ako25 Cannot tell you what "the recommended practice" is - just my opinion on it: I don't indent sections - Section changes happen too infrequently to justify full *horizontal indentation* (once the indented area is longer than a screenful, it is not of much use anyhow). I do, however, try to make sure a section directive stands out *vertically* - That is, I tend to insert 2-3 empty lines above and at least one empty line below such lines.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Microsoft "C" functions, the actual function names will have a leading underscore. For 32 bit mode assembly, include language type in the .model directive:

```
        .model  flat,c      ;for 32 bit mode only, no underscores needed
```

This eliminates the need to use underscores in function names. In 64 bit mode, the .model directive doesn't seem to be allowed, but it appears to default to .model flat,c .

On a side note, Visual Studio 2015 and later default to an "inlines" printf (and some other stuff) in C source files. There is a legacy version that can be used from assembly code. Example include lib statements.

```
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions        ;for printf
```