# Mixing C++ and Assembly in visual studio gives linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, linker

I was trying to follow up a tutorial on mixing c++ and x86_assembly with masm on visual studio

I have done all the steps after the instructor and the same steps found repeated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751509/external-assembly-file-in-visual-studio) all the steps mentioned is done except for step 8 `8) Change the Active solution platform to x64`

After Doing all the above steps on trying to build the solution it gives about 18 errors of LNK2019

The error is resolved only when I remove the asm file from the solution

here is my c++ code

```
// CalculatreSum.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

#include <iostream>

extern "C" int AdderAsm(int, int, int);
int AdderCpp(int, int, int);

int main() {
    int sum;
    sum = AdderCpp(4, 5, 6);
    printf("Sum from AdderCpp is: %d\n", sum);
    sum = AdderAsm(4, 5, 6);
    printf("Sum from AdderAsm is: %d\n", sum);
}

int AdderCpp(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

and here is my x86 assembly one

```
.386
.model flat, c

.code 

AdderAsm proc
    push    ebp;
    mov     ebp, esp;

    mov     eax, [ebp + 8];
    mov     ebx, [ebp + 12];
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 16];

    add     eax, ebx;
    add     eax, ecx;

    pop     ebp;

    ret

AdderAsm    ENDP
END         AdderAsm
```

[EDIT]
The Error messages in the log

```
17 unresolved externals C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\Debug\CalculatreSum.exe   1   
unresolved external symbol _strcat_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z) C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)  1   
unresolved external symbol _strcpy_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z) C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)  1   
unresolved external symbol _terminate referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) 1   
unresolved external symbol _wcscpy_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)    C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INIT C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj)   1   
unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INITW   C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj)   1   
unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4    C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4gs.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func referenced in function _printf    C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum.obj   1   
unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function __vfprintf_l   C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum.obj   1   
unresolved external symbol __wmakepath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)    C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol __wsplitpath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)   C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol ___current_exception referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept   C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) 1   
unresolved external symbol ___current_exception_context referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept   C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) 1   
unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function __vsprintf_s_l C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)  1   
unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)  C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleHandleW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)    C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1   
unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_LoadLibraryExW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)  C:\Users\mahmo\source\repos\CalculatreSum\CalculatreSum\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)    1
```

Comment: Oh, according to [Naming convention for labels, functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541008), `.model flat,c` decorates with a leading `_` for you.  So maybe you have some other link error.  But you didn't quote them so we don't know what they are / what problem we're actually trying to find / fix.  So the question should have been closed as lacking [mcve] (error message details), rather than duplicate, but it should still be closed until those details are added.

Comment: @beothunder: that phrasing was a bit confusing, but they *are* building as 32-bit, which presumably is the default so they *didn't* switch the file or project to x64.  If they tried to assemble this source file as x64, you're right the `push    ebp` wouldn't assemble, so you'd have some `A...` errors and not get to the stage of seeing LNK errors.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright I copied the linking errors from the log into the Question

Comment: You call `printf`, but you didn't include `<stdio.h>`  (And you include `<iostream>` for no apparent reason; that might be pulling in some dependencies you don't need?).  IDK what Visual Studio's defaults are for linking libraries with C++/asm projects, but that seems odd.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's just the same code the instructor wrote and it's compiling and running perfectly  when I remove the asm file so that's not the problem obviously

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the assembly file and go to properties. From there change Item Type to "Microsoft Macro Assembler"

[image]